# Am i to install a package on Pycharm to enable me use pd.read_clipboard() function?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, clipboard, revenue

I am trying to use few lines of a data online in pycharm. i copied the lines i needed, went to pycharm

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
```

Output :

```
line 2872, in _alert_malformed
    raise ParserError(msg) pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 4 fields in line 4, saw 5. 
Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Comment: `read_clipboard()` is working already, and it's complaining that your clipboard does not have proper format of a dataframe. Specifically, `line 4` has more fields than the others.

Comment: which means what i copied from the internet, should be edited before copying to clipboard right?